# Set theory self taught (check if my logic is okay)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am a beginner in set theory and I really do not feel confident writing proofs so a help would be much appreciated. I am not a mathematician by any stretch but I always felt like math is an essential tool and so I am setting myself into this adventure of learning it.
Here's where I am struggling:
Problem: let $R$ be a binary relation Proof that 
$R^{-1}[R[A]]\supseteq A\cap domR$ 
with $domR$ being the domain of $R$ and $ranR$ being its range


My proof :) "Don't laugh"
$R^{-1}[R[A]]=\{x:x \; \in  dom R \; and \; \exists y\;(y \in R[A] \; and \; xRy)\}$
which mean
$R^{-1}[R[A]]=\{x:x \; \in  dom R \; and \; \exists y \; \exists x' \; (y \in ran R \; and \; x' \in A  \; and \; \; x'Ry\; and \; \; xRy)\}$
Now let 
$x \in A \cap domR $ then 
$x \in domR \; and \; \exists y \exists x'(y \in ran R\; and \;x'=x \in A\; and \;xRy) $
Thus 
$x \in R^{-1}[R[A]]$

Should I give up and do something more productive with my life?

Comment: You can use `\text{dom}` or `\operatorname{dom}` to get a better looking, non-italic "dom" in math mode.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to start on the right because we want to show the inclusion from right to left. And the proof then follwos from definitions in a simple way:

Let $x \in \text{dom} R \cap A$. So $x \in A$ and $x \in \text{dom} R$ which implies that $xRy$ for some $y$. This $y \in R[A]$ by definition, which then again by definition makes that $xRy$ is a witness to the fact that $x \in R^{-1}[R[A]]$. So we're done showing the inclusion.

Comment: Hello Henno, thanks for your answer! it makes senses now but then another problem arises.
How come the inclusion is not right in the other direction? from your definition I cannot see any difference between the $R^{-1}[R[A]]$ and $A \cap \operatorname{dom}R$ in other word how come $R^{-1}[R[A]] \; \nsubseteq \;A \cap \operatorname{dom}R$

Comment: Because $x \in R^{-1}[R[A]]$ does not always imply that $x \in A$. @BeFHumble If we interpret $xRy$ as $x \le y$ on $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$, e.g. and $A=\Bbb N$ then $-1 \in R^{-1}[R[A]]$ as witnessed by $-1 R 2$ and $2 \in R[A]$ is witnessed by $1 R 2$ and $1 \in A$, etc. But $-1 \notin A$.

Comment: Hello Henno, it is clear to me now. Thank you.